# timeit module - get fastest and slowest loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeit

I would like to do some benchmarking with Python's timeit module. Is there a way to make timeit return the times for the slowest as well as the fastest loop out of 1000 loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is pretty easy to hack. You should be able to copy the `timeit.py` [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py), save it to `my_timeit.py`, edit it slightly, and then use it as a new module.

You can see on [line 326](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#l326) that `timeit.py` does `best = min(r)`; you can add in `worst = max(r)` and edit the print statements below.

Answer (score 3):

`timeit` returns "best of 3" i.e., there are *two* parameters: one specifies number of iterations in a loop, another how many times to repeat the loop. The result that is passed to `min()` is the time *per loop*, not per iteration of the loop.

The point of repeating the loop is to exclude the influence from other processes on the same system -- from the docs (`help('timeit')`):

> The best thing to do when accurate timing is necessary is to repeat
>   the timing a few times and use the best time.  The -r option is good
>   for this; the default of 3 repetitions is probably enough in most
>   cases.

It doesn't make sense to repeat the measarements 1000  times. You probably meant to specify 1000 iteration for a single loop (default is 1000000).

Only the fastest loop (minimum time) is useful -- from `help('timeit.Timer.repeat')`:

> Note: it's tempting to calculate mean and standard deviation from the
>   result vector and report these.  However, this is not very useful.  In
>   a typical case, the lowest value gives a lower bound for how fast your
>   machine can run the given code snippet; **higher values in the result
>   vector are typically not caused by variability in Python's speed, but
>   by other processes interfering with your timing accuracy.**  So the
>   min() of the result is probably the only number you should be
>   interested in.  After that, you should look at the entire vector and
>   apply common sense rather than statistics.<sub>emphasis is mine</sub>

i.e., the slowest loop indicates how much other processes can interfere with the measurements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import timeit

def your_function():
    "do something"

t = timeit.Timer(your_function)
# repeat 10 times, 1000000 times through the loop
repeat, number = 10, 1000000
r = t.repeat(repeat, number) 
best, worse = min(r), max(r)
print("{number} loops, best of {repeat}: {best:.3g} seconds per loop, "
     "worse of {repeat}: {worse:.3g} seconds per loop".format(**vars()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [repeat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) function instead of `timeit`, which return a list of times.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`timeit.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat)

```
res = timeit.repeat('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(1000))', number=1, repeat=10)

fastest = min(res)
slowest = max(res)
```

If you want multiple executions (say `n`) for each repeat don't forget to divide the results by `n`

```
n = 100
res = timeit.repeat('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(1000))', number=n, repeat=10)

fastest = min(res)/n
slowest = max(res)/n

print(fastest, slowest)
# Out:
# 0.00020186356006888674 0.0002322985901264474
```